# how to remove all uncheck items from listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i need to remove all unchecked item from listview winforms c# in textchange event

for e.g i need to do like below

```
private void textBox_supplierName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (listView_supplierNames.CheckedItems==CheckState.Unchecked)
  {
        // remove item    
  }
}
```

how to do it ...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the ListView Items and Use [ListViewItem.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Remove Items

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView_supplierNames.Items)
            {
                if (item.Checked)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    //Remove unchecked Items
                     listView1.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ListViewItem.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to remove item from its associated ListView control:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView_supplierNames.Items)
    if (!item.Checked)
        item.Remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Get all the unchecked items and use Remove - example-

```
foreach(var item in listView.SelectedItems)
{
   listView.Items.Remove(item)
}
```

Comment: here by listView.SelectedItems i assumed that list would contain only  the unchecked items.